# How to rewrite url

Tags: .htaccess

I need help to rewrite my URL, already user posted this kind similar questions but its not useful for us.

My link is

http://www.domain.com/pages/content/2

Now I want url like this:

http://www.domain.com/faq.html

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^more/([^/]*)\.html$ /more.php?id=$1 [L]
```